# Open panel over li

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to open panel over ul not pushing ul and then open panel..It must slide from top to bottom

The code is:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Collapsible Panel</h2>
<button data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">dasda</button>
  <div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body"><ul><li>asda</li><li>asda</li><li>asda</li><li>asda</li><li>asda</li></ul></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<ul><li>asda</li><li>asda</li><li>asda</li><li>asda</li><li>asda</li></ul>

</body>
</html>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/actmxzzm/)
any suggestion plz?

**EDIT**

Onclick of button panel's li would be open over another li..In my code when I am clicking,it is pushing down the li then panel open..Just like [example](http://jsfiddle.net/2Hv5f/40/) happend..but I want to open from top to button on click of button in my code

Comment: @1l13v added a jsfiddle

Comment: another bootstrap frenzy

Comment: Please explain your question little bit.

Comment: @JohnR edited question.

Comment: you can achieve this with `position: absolute` but I think in your case it won't be a good solution

Comment: @1l13v done by setting 'position:absolute;z-index:9999;background-color:gainsboro'..thanku

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: absolute;` or `position: fixed;` on the element you want to go over the top of the other elements. [This JSFiddle demonstrates](http://jsfiddle.net/actmxzzm/1/). Keep them bound in a parent that you can then treat as any other element and position as required. This means the parent takes no account of the child when organising it's content. [Here is some more detail](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/).

Note, you'll need to rethink the positioning of other elements, but the desired effect is achieved.

This works because the new position values take the element out of the flow of the document meaning that other child elements no longer flow around it. They flow around the other elements that are still in the flow of the document.

Comment: thnku for ur response ..I solved by using some css from ur given link

Comment: noo. Adding css rules to bootstrap component (class) is very bad. Did ou check what a mess is in the fiddle?

Comment: @1l13v my answer will help explain some of the underlying stuff that you still need to know to use a framework effectively, there may be a class that achieves the same in bootstrap, but it's helpful to know what's going on at a document / css level

Answer (score 0):

You should add your own class to the panel you want to hover other elements, like this:

`<div class="panel-group my-panel">`
and add this css rule:

```
.my-panel{
    position: absolute;
    top: 90px;
    left: 15px;
}
```

Try it in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/actmxzzm/4/)

Note: this is not very desirable solution, but in simple situations can serve you well.

Comment: Why is it not desirable?

Comment: because you have to hard code your position (left and top in this case)

Comment: that's not strictly true, you can hard-code your left and top values, but you could also use something more flexible like %, or contain them all in something that you then position, leaving them as defaults, or you could use a preprocessor / calc() to work them out - the basic 'float this over that' problem is well solved by position absolute, IMO

Comment: yes, but if you have your button and panel pushed a little bit down, what then? You have to change top value again. It's not flexible